# Extending injectivity of closed sets in injective immersions

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to do the following exercise :

> A $C^1$ immersion $f:M\rightarrow N$ which is injective on a closed subset $F\subset M$ is injective on a neighborhood of $F$. In fact $f$ has a neighborhood  $ V\subset C_S^1(M,N)$ and $F$ has a neighborhood $U\subset M$ such that every $g\in V$ is injective on $U$. If $K$ is compact $V$ can be taken in $C_W^1(M,N)$.

Focusing only on the first part of the problem that is the part where can extend injectivity of closed sets ininjective immersions.
I have been thinking about this for a while and there are two ideas, either I construct the neighborhood , I have tried this using the fact that $f$ is locally injective , or I go by contradiction but I can't get anytihing. Either way I got nowhere useful and was wondering if there is anything else that I can try or if there is something I am missing ?

Any advice on this is aprecciated. Thanks !

Comment: I think you cannot assume that $f(F_i')$ and $f(M-U_i)$ are disjoint. I don't think you can prove this without further shrinking $U$, by the way.

Comment: Yeah I agree , gotta think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Proper maps are closed maps; immersions are locally injective.
Then try to construct the neighborhood on a countable series of ordered compact subsets , with induction.

Comment: Sorry but this is very vague, that is the general strategy for sure. You should give an hint to accomplish the hard part not the obvious part of the exercise : )